# Filtering an OpenAPI spec using jq

Tags: jq, openapi

I have an OpenAPI spec where some of the endpoints are tagged as `public`.

I want to filter this with `jq` so that:

1. Endpoints that are not tagged as public are removed;
2. Other parts of the OpenAPI spec are left as they are;
3. Optionally, the `public` tag is removed.

I am completely lost with this, and don't even know where to begin. I'm open to any solution that can run on the command line. It doesn't have to be `jq`.

I have tried a lot of different `jq` filters, but none of them get me anywhere close to where I want to be.

This is an example input

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test OpenAPI specification",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "example.com"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/public": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "publicOperation",
        "summary": "Public operation",
        "description": "This is a public operation that should appear in the public-facing OpenAPI spec",
        "tags": [
          "System",
          "public"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "security": [
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "OK"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/error"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/private": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "privateOperation",
        "summary": "Private operation",
        "description": "This is a private operation that should not appear in the public OpenAPI",
        "tags": [
          "System",
          "private"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "security": [
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "OK"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/error"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/neither": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "neitherPublicNorPrivate",
        "summary": "Neither public nor private",
        "description": "This operation is not tagged as either public or private and it should not appear in the pulic-facing OpenAPI spec",
        "tags": [
          "System"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "security": [
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "OK"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "Authorization": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "error": {
        "description": "Error response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "message": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "code": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "issues": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "message"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                  }
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "message",
                "code"
              ],
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I'd like to see as my output

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test OpenAPI specification",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "example.com"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/public": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "publicOperation",
        "summary": "Public operation",
        "description": "This is a public operation that should appear in the public-facing OpenAPI spec",
        "tags": [
          "System"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "security": [
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "OK"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "Authorization": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "error": {
        "description": "Error response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "message": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "code": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "issues": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "message"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                  }
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "message",
                "code"
              ],
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.paths |= with_entries(select(.value.get?.tags[] | contains("public")))
```

Will update the `paths` object to just the result of `select(.value.get?.tags[] | contains("public"))` which filters out any object where `tags` does not include `public`

Output:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test OpenAPI specification",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "example.com"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/public": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "publicOperation",
        "summary": "Public operation",
        "description": "This is a public operation that should appear in the public-facing OpenAPI spec",
        "tags": [
          "System",
          "public"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "security": [
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "OK"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "Authorization": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "error": {
        "description": "Error response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "message": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "code": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "issues": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "message"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                  }
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "message",
                "code"
              ],
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jVumLTvL_p1)

---

To remove the `public` from the `.get.tags`, use

```
.paths |= with_entries(select(.value.get?.tags[] | contains("public")) | .value.get.tags |= map(select(. != "public")))
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_O99Oxpa1Fy)

Comment: That's not quite what I need.

I need the `paths` object to include only objects that have `public` in the `tags` in their descendants. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Regarding your 3th point, will there always be just 1 path with public in the tags? If not, how would you like to see that if you don't want the /public key?

Comment: Your updated answer is perfect, thank you! 

For the third point, I think there may be misunderstanding, probably caused by my badly-worded question! I want 

`"tags": [
          "System",
          "public"
        ],`

To change to 


`"tags": [
          "System"
        ],`

In other words, I want to remove only the element with the value "public" from the `tags` array. There may be multiple `tags` arrays in the JSON.

Comment: You can add `.value.get.tags |= map(select(. != "public"))` behind the other select - I've added it to my asnwer

Comment: Works perfectly on my test data. On my live spec, I had to update it slightly to `.paths |= with_entries(select(.value.get?.tags[]? | contains("public")))`

Comment: One final question for you @0stone0. In my example files,  the children of `paths` always contained just a `get`. In a real OpenAPI spec, the structure is more complex - they can contain a `get` and/or a `post` and/or `put` etc. Can the filter be updated to take this into account? Maybe using something like `.value.(get | post | put).tags[]?` ?

Comment: Nitpick: The expression `.value.get?.tags[] | contains("public")` matches not only the tag `"public"` but also stuff like `"not_public"`. The comparison is string to string, not list to string.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here's a solution that works regardless of the name of the HTTP verb ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e3X40uBz17a)):

```
  (.paths[][] |= select( [.tags[] | . == "public"] | any ) ) 
| (.paths[]   |= select( (. | length) > 0 )) 
| (.paths[][].tags[] |= select( . != "public" ))
```

You can leave the last line out if you do not want to remove the "public" tag from the `tags[]` array.

### Explanation

We start by noticing that the value of the `.paths` attribute is structured as follows:

```
endpoints
└── operations 
    └── tags
```

We can take a three-step approach as follows:

- STEP-1: Remove every operation that is not public i.e., an operation that does not have at least one tag called "public".
- STEP-2: Remove every endpoint that does not have at least one public operation.
- STEP-3: Remove the "public" tag from the tags under each endpoint.

#### STEP-1

Here's the filter to remove non-public operations:

```
(.paths[][] |= select( [.tags[] | . == "public"] | any ) )
```

It works as follows:

- `.paths[][]` chooses each operation; the successive `[]` descend one level each.
- `|=` says we are going to modify each operation; so the `select` clause is running on each operation.
- `[.tags[] | . = "public"] | any` is unpacking the tags array for an operation, checking if each element in that array is equal to "public" returning an array that contains true/false elements, and then the `any` clause checks that at least one of the elements is true.
- `select ( <condition> )` only retains those `tag` elements where the condition is true, i.e., only operations that have a tag called "public".

#### STEP-2

At this point, in your example, we would have all the operations under `/private` and `/neither` removed and so the JSON for the paths object would be:

```
{ 
  "/public" : { get : { /* the operation */ },
  "/private" : {},
  "/neither" : {}
}
```

Now, we need to remove each endpoint that is an empty object i.e., an endpoint that does not have any public operations.

Here's the filter to do that:

```
( .paths[] |= select( (. | length) > 0 ))
```

It works as follows:

- `.paths[]` chooses each endpoint as the `[]` descends one level.
- `|=` says we are going to modify each operation; so the `select` clause is running on each endpoint.
- `(. | length) > 0 )` is checking that each operation (i.e. the selected object) has at least one key. The length operation on an object returns how many keys it has.
- `select ( <condition> )` only retains those endpoints that have some keys, i.e., excludes endpoints without any operations.

#### STEP-3

Now, our JSON has what we need except the extraneous "public" tag under the `tags[]` array of each operation. We can remove those using this filter:

```
.paths[][].tags[] |= select( . != "public" )
```

It works as follows:

- `.paths[][].tags[]` chooses each tag element
- `|=` is operating on each tag
- `. != "public"` is checking that the value of each tag (represented by `.` here) is not equal to public.
- `select( <condition> )` is therefore retaining only tags that are equal to `public`.

#### Finally...

The `|` between the clauses is essentially passing the JSON after being modified from the first filter to the second to the third resulting in:

```
  (.paths[][] |= select( [.tags[] | . == "public"] | any ) ) 
| (.paths[]   |= select( (. | length) > 0 )) 
| (.paths[][].tags[] |= select( . != "public" ))
```